# Flutter app screen page does not automatic load content unless uisng hot reload on VScode(ctrl + s)

Tags: flutter

hi i am new at android vscode with flutter and im looking for solution on which after i login the registered account from firebase database to the app i am building it will load the registered full name of the user along-side the email on the profile page. I am using a bottom navigationbar on which if i click different button in the app and go back to the profile page the posted text become null. but if i stay it on profile page it and press ctrl+s (hot reload) on vs code it will show the data.
heres my code for profile(this is different from the homepage)

> 

here is the screenshot after hot reload it
[image: here is the screenshot after hot reload it]

and this is after clicking other button
[image]

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stock_market_tracker_v3/Models/User_Models.dart';
import 'package:stock_market_tracker_v3/Screens/LoginPage.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();

  @override
 void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value){
      this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
    });
     super.initState();
 }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Welcome!"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: Image.asset("Asset/images/levi.gif", fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Welcome back",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
               Text("${loggedInUser.firstName} ${loggedInUser.lastname}",
  
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),

              Text("${loggedInUser.email}",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
              const SizedBox(height: 15,
              ),
              ActionChip(label: const Text("Logout"), onPressed: (){
                logout(context);
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> logout(BuildContext context)async
  {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
  }
} '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     @override
 void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
     super.initState();
     loadData();

 }

loadData() async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value){
           setState((){
             this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
              });
        });
}
```

Try This

Comment: Hi sir now im facing problem, im using two way login in which are email login, and google account. if i login using google i manage to show name and email from google but the User collection show null in text in the display

Comment: Hi Frederick, I need to see the code to make a comment